# How do i add rich texts (suggestion chips) in wordpress plugin chatbot integrated with dialogflow for free?

Tags: wordpress, dialogflow-es, chatbot, richtext, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How do I integrate rich texts (suggestion chips) in my dialogflow without using facebook or any other platform? I want to add suggestion chips in default responses only. Can custom payload help me do that? Please give a step-by-step guide as to how I can do it and I do not know the language JSON so could you give me an example of it which I can later modify? I am a student and a beginner.

Comment: Which Wordpress plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add rich messages using Google Assistant and custom payload. Google Assistant helps to implement rich messages is an easier and simpler way to add rich messages without writing any code. Please refer to this [doc](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/rich-message-button-response-dialogflow-chatbot/) for more info. 
You can also integrate with third-party applications like kommunicate and use the pre-defined custom payloads which have many options to customize.